# Can't install windows on my pc

Tags: windows, memory, installation

I started receiving blue screen error `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT`. I ran Windows memory diagnostic tool. I tried all three method `Basic,Standard,Advance` it didn't detected any fault. So i tried re-installing windows . After install(getting started windows after windows installation) it shows me error windows is not able to install correctly reinstall windows or windows installation is corrupted.

My windows installation media is not corrupted i have install windows with same media in other device right after it gave me error

I have not formatted my drive for installation.

Previously before receiving `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT` error my system hangs and on restart it gives me continuous beep sound then i have to remove ram and reinsert it to fix the problem after few days beep sound automatically resolved and `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT` error start occurring.

Test Results from memtest86
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a dying motherboard... is it worth flogging a dead horse?! Have you tried new memory sticks in the machine?

Comment: Not dead yet its quite new just a year old.... Nope i haven't. i don't have any extra memory

Comment: Have you tried memtest86? How much memory do you have?

Comment: Single stick ADATA 4GB DDR3 1600Mz

Comment: nope i haven't i will give it a try

Comment: Age has nothing to do with a motherboard failing, sounds like a flaky memory controller, if the memory controller is part of the CPU, then it could be a faulty CPU and not motherboard.